# getting an socket reset error while sending a mail through java mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have written a java program to send a mail and it is working fine but sometimes i get this error , please advise what this error is about and how can i overcome from this

```
javax.mail.StoreClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 1):

[Networks fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing), you need to be prepared to handle it.

Why exactly it's failing in this case is hard to say.  The server could be closing the connection because it's overloaded.  Your firewall could be closing the connection because it's out of resources.  Your router could be failing.  The list goes on and on.

The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide more clues, but most likely you'll need to do some low level network debugging if you really want to know why.